# Counting number of points in particular polygon for list of individuals using R?

Tags: shapefile, polygon, r

I have distribution points for a set of individuals and a file of polygons-with matching IDs.

What I would like to do is to go through and for each individual find the total number of points and the number which fall within the appropriate polygon, then have the output in spreadsheet form with a column for ID; Total number of points; points in polygon.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `poly.counts` tool in the [GISTools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GISTools/GISTools.pdf) package.

[image]

[image]

---

```
require(GISTools)

# Use a sample dataset
data(newhaven)

# Plot the sample data (For illustration purposes)
plot(blocks)
plot(breach, add = TRUE)

# Count points within each polygon
counts = poly.counts(breach,blocks)

# Convert the counts to a dataframe
df = data.frame(counts)

#Write the dataframe to a .csv file
setwd("C:/temp")
write.table(df, file = "dataframe.csv", sep = ",", col.names = NA) 

# For fun: Compute densities and map them in a choropleth map
choropleth(blocks,counts/poly.areas(blocks))
```

Answer (score 1):

The package rgeos has the function

```
gContains
```

It's help page says

> gContains returns TRUE if none of the point of spgeom2 is outside of
>   spgeom1 and at least one point of spgeom2 falls within spgeom1.

If you run this over each distribution point inside the function 'which', you will get a vector that you can then analyse with 'table'

Give us a reproducible example (using the shapefiles in maptools etc) and we might be able to give code for a reproducible answer...